# Notifications stating Trojans found on Fedora 37

Tags: fedora, security, clamav

I help friends manage systems which feature Fedora OS. They have been reporting that notifications are being highlighted mentioning the presence of Trojans and such and they are alarmed. I generally believe that little if any are serious as I have Selinux Enabled and a Firewall setup on these units. All units are behind routers.
I decided to install a few applications such as `clamav`, `rkhunter` and `chkrootkit` on my own units and gave them a run. Neither `rkhunter` nor `chkrootkit` showed anything remarkable but `clamav` did. I list a few of them for context:

```
Found 76 possible threats (224741 files scanned).

/home/me/.mozilla/firefox/b9w9hqme.default-1635637832461  /extensions/support@lastpass.com.xpi                                        PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1              
/home/me/.mozilla/icecat/h2020a74.default/extensions/support@lastpass.com.xpi                                                       PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1              
/home/me/.cache/mozilla/firefox/b9w9hqme.default-1635637832461/cache2/entries/7B869B1E4FEB0079533855B292DEDC9F049750CD              PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1              
/home/me/.cache/mozilla/firefox/b9w9hqme.default-1635637832461/cache2/entries/6BA4FE386CA8001456C08ADCC0D8047E35A2BD77              PUA.Win.Exploit.CVE_2012_1461-1
   ....................

 /home/me/.cache/microsoft-edge-beta/Default/Cache/Cache_Data/c6dd4acd03fcf165_0                                                     PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1              
/home/me/.cache/microsoft-edge-beta/Default/Cache/Cache_Data/16fb8756c668ad8b_0                                                     PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1              

    ......................
/home/me/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd/4.123.0.2_0/oidc-client.min.js                   PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1              
/home/me/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd/4.123.0.2_0/lpfulllib.js                         PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1
```

Is clamav being over zealous or should one actually quarantine them?
Robert

Comment: https://github.com/jensyt/imurmurhash-js/issues/1

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1006237/clamav-detects-trojans

Comment: https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=154107

Comment: [PUA FAQ](https://docs.clamav.net/faq/faq-pua.html#current-pua-categories "check Disclaimer")

Answer (score 0):

> I generally believe that little if any are serious as I have Selinux Enabled and a Firewall setup on these units.

I'm not sure what you base that confidence on. It's wrong.

We clearly see in your log that the warnings affect files within the user's home directory, affecting multiple browsers. If the issue found there is actually malware, it's game over at that point. The security measures have already failed or never applied. In this case, they never applied, because this is user-installed browser extensions, which is something that users want to be able to install themselves, so no general SELinux mechanism could ever inhibit them.

SELinux is meant to avoid a fixed-functionality program accessing data and functionality it shouldn't. But this has already failed.

Again, **if** this is malware, all your friend's user data is to be considered compromised. All the things they enter in one of these browser is potentially compromised.

Note that these warnings are "PUA", potentially unwanted applications, not viruses.

> Is clamav being over zealous or should one actually quarantine them?

You're explicitly checking for PUAs, it seems. So it's not ClamAV that's overly zealous – it's the user who explicitly said "Oh, please scan for things that aren't known to be malware, but which we can't rule out might potentially have malware usage". That is a very broad category, and one with likely many false positives. I won't give advice regarding how to consider your specific warnings.

> quarantine them

Never in my life has "quarantining files" made sense. Either the file is infected, then by all sensible means, get rid of it, or it's not.

If that file is part of a software installation, moving it, making it otherwise inaccessible or deleting it will likely render the software broken. So, the whole idea of "oh, I found a virus, but I can let the user continue working as before by just moving it out of its place" is … strange to me. In this case, if you "quarantined", deleted or whatever'ed these files, your browser is likely to tell you it can't load the affected extension, or to just behave incorrectly, or crash. Great solution, really.

Seriously, antivirus is really a last-resort measure. The moment an infected file appears on your system, it's time to erase the whole system, install it fresh and restore valuable data from backup; you've been had, there's only damage control from here on. For every login done or login credentials stored on that machine that is not part of a multi-factor authentication scheme, you'll want to change the password after. You will want to close all existing sessions regardless of whether you had multi-factor authentication.

Your system got compromised, and you learned about it after the fact through antivirus. That's not a preventive measure, that's just diagnosis.

Note, again, that ClamAV doesn't claim to have found malware. It says it found something that it thinks might potentially have file features that might be used to potentially implement malware, potentially.

Comment: "so no general SELinux mechanism could ever inhibit them." — well, it _could_, via policies that default to deny, but when we had that (long ago), people were frustrated because was too restrictive.

Comment: nah, I'll argue that "inhibits the intended use" is simply not a viable rule; it's not "too restrictive", it's "denying usage of the same thing it strives to protect". But I think: who am I to tell *you* about user-facing SELinux, you're definitely more of an expert on that than I am :)